# Jquery .change on checkboxes in array

Tags: jquery, webforms

This is a asp.net webforms page with nested gridviews.

I have a table that dynamically adds multiple "details" tables under each row.
The details table has a "select all" checkbox in a header and a checkbox for each row under it.

I am trying to select all child row checkboxes when the header level checkbox is checked.

```
<div>
<table class="details">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <th scope="col">
                <span class="ckbSelectAll">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </span>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">number</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="ckbResults">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>121223</td>
            <td>Open</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can find all the header level checkboxes (ckbSelectAll) by looking for the class and finding the checkbox. I see that I have an array of all the header level checkboxes, but the .change does not seem to fire on any of them.

```
$.each($('.ckbSelectAll input[type="checkbox"]'),function (index, value) {
$(value).change(function () {
    alert('checked');
}) });
```

I thought it might be the .change and I have tried with .on('change', function() and .on('click', function()   but just cannot get the click or change to trigger the alert.

Comment: `$.each()` is designed for Array or Objects. `.each()` is suggested. Like so: `$('.ckbSelectAll input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(ind, el){ $(el).change(function(){ alert("checked"); }); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my issue was with the sub tables. They are visible when inspecting the page but do not display until a user expands them. I used the same JavaScript I have in the question,

```
$.each($('.ckbSelectAll input[type="checkbox"]'),function (index, value) { $(value).change(function () {
alert('checked'); }) });
```

but made it a function that is called on expand. This is now hooking up to the selectors properly and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

This is best done using `.each()` and `.prop()`.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6Lowt85a/

**HTML**

```
<table class="details">
  <thead>
    <tr style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <th scope="col">
        <span class="ckbSelectAll">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        </span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">number</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="ckbResults">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>112233</td>
      <td>Open</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="ckbResults">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>112234</td>
      <td>Open</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="ckbResults">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>112235</td>
      <td>Open</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".ckbSelectAll input").change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    $(".ckbResults input").each(function(index, elem) {
      $(elem).prop("checked", checked);
    });
  });
});
```

**Update**

In the case of multiple tables, I would advise something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".ckbSelectAll input").change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    var parentTable = $(this).closest("table");
    parentTable.find(".ckbResults input").each(function(index, elem) {
      $(elem).prop("checked", checked);
    });
  });
});
```

When the checkbox in a specific header is clicked, the associated checkboxes in that table will be checked or unchecked.

Comment: The main problem is there are multiple tables added that have the "ckbSelectAll" checkbox added. So I need to watch each of those and know when one is changed as checking one select all should only select the checkoxes in it's table.

Comment: @InsertOldUserIDHere easy enough. You can do it in a few ways. Watch each like you suggest or marry the actions to a specific parent.

Comment: Right, that is the part I can't get working. I can see that I get all the checkboxes in the .each, but I cannot seem to capture the change event on them. If I can get that, I can check all the rest. But the '(value).change(function ()' never triggers so I can't do the rest

Comment: @InsertOldUserIDHere if you look at my answer and how I bind the `.change()` to the class selector, you would not need to have to do this. The `change` callback would be bound to all elements that match that selector. Then when you call `$(this)` or `this` it will relate to the specific element that was changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code even if you have more than 1 table in same page, just make sure the `main checkbox` have `ckbSelectAll` class:

```
$('.ckbSelectAll > input').on('change', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('thead')
        .next()
        .find('input[type=checkbox]')
        .prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
});
```

Notice that if you have some checkboxes in `tbody` that you don't want to get effect with your code, simply add `css-class` to `sub-checkboxes` (I mean checkboxes that you need to check/un-check with `main checkbox`) and change the code as follow:

```
$('.ckbSelectAll > input').on('change', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('thead')
        .next()
        .find('input[type=checkbox].my-class-name')
        .prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddnfmxgz/)